# RegEx for capturing everything except numbers and one word

Tags: regex

I am quite stuck with a regex I can't get to work. It should capture everything except digits and the word `fiktiv` (not single characters of it!). Objective is to get rid of this content.

I have tried something like `(?!\d|fiktiv).*` on my sample string `123456788daswqrt fiktiv`

https://regex101.com/r/kU8mF3/1

However this does match the `fiktiv` at the end as well.

Comment: What language are you using. In most programming languages to get rid of the content you'd match it and then replace it with empty string. So for example on the command line (assuming unix): `awk '{gsub(/fiktiv/,"");gsub(/[0-9]/,"";print $0}'`

Comment: I guess you just need `.replace(/(fiktiv)|\D/g, "$1")` (in JS). What is the regex flavor and what is the expected output?

Comment: that would be `\d`

Comment: I am using SQL Server which under the cover uses a .NET assembly

Comment: So, can you use `Regex.Replace(input, "(fiktiv)|[^0-9]", "$1")`? Or are you limited to TSQL toolset? See https://regex101.com/r/vR4uU0/1

Comment: I am using this CLR assembly:[link]https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/  However I couldn't get the advice to work properly.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the answers. I was trying to tune a function on SQL Server in order to get better performance. However CLR Regex functions do need more CPU than the very limited TSQL functions available. Therefore I skipped working on the issue.

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85954/Use-RegEx-in-SQL-with-CLR-Procs

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to use a neglected character class, which can be used by putting a ^ in [] braces. So you basically say don't match digits, and as many non digits as you can get until a space occurs and the word fiktiv appears.

This capturing will be "saved" in the capturing group 1 for later use.

```
([^\d]+)\s+fiktiv
```

Testing could be done here:

https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks for your help...but I am still struggling to prevent the word fiktiv getting matched

Comment: @MartinGuth: You should not try to avoid matching it, as it will make the regex inefficient and slow, see my approach: https://regex101.com/r/vR4uU0/1

Comment: The concept behind regex to strip out the unneeded characters by having output in so called capturing groups. Even if you explicitly state fiktiv in the regex and it gets matched, the capturing group number 1 will only contain what the () braces are wrapped around, so : [^\d]+ in this example. You need to find out how the output can access the capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

> It should capture everything except digits and the word `fiktiv` (not single characters of it!). Objective is to get rid of this content.

So, you want to remove any character that is not a digit (that is, `\D` or `[^0-9]`  pattern) and not a `fiktiv` char sequence.

You may use a regex with a capturing group and alternation:

```
(fiktiv)|[^0-9]
```

and replace with the contents of Group 1 using a `$1` backreference, `fiktiv`, to restore it in the replaced string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dG1bP2/1)

C# implementation:

```
Regex.Replace(input‌​, "(fiktiv)|[^0-9]", "$1")
```

Also, see [*Use RegEx in SQL with CLR Procs*](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85954/Use-RegEx-in-SQL-with-CLR-Procs).